# How to draw only a part of arc in canvas

Tags: android

I'm developing an analog clock widget and the dial of clock is an image.
I want to draw an arc segment like in the image(as shown in orange).

```
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 200, paint);
```

I tried with drawcircle and also with drawArc but could not proceed since i want only a part of arc and not a complete arc. Any ideas ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made this class hope it help you, all variable are in spanish but its quite simple,

the constructor SemiCirculo use as parameters the rgb for the semicircle and the resolution (number of triangles for your semicircle)

the CalcularPuntosPorcentaje method use as parameters the center of the circle, the starting angle, the widht of the angle, and the radio.

the method ImprimeCirculo use the canvas as parameter, it is used to draw the semicircle once it has allready been calcultaed the points of the semicircle with the previus mentioned method.

the CalcularPuntosPorcentaje method is similar to CalcularPuntosPorcentaje, but insted of the starting and the widht angle parameters it use a % from 0 to 100

finaly the SetOffset and SetColor are used to change the default starting poing o reference for the angle and the color of the semicircle

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;


public class SemiCirculo {

    private Path circulo;
    private Paint color;
    private float px, py, radio, anguloI, anchoa,offset;
    private int r, g, b;
    private int resolucion;
    private float puntox[],puntoy[];


    public SemiCirculo(int r1, int g1, int b1, int resolucion1) {

        this.offset = 0;
        this.color = new Paint();
        this.r = r1;
        this.g = g1;
        this.b = b1;
        this.color.setColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
        color.setAntiAlias(true);
        circulo = new Path();
        this.resolucion = resolucion1;
        this.puntox = new float[this.resolucion];
        this.puntoy = new float[this.resolucion];
        this.anguloI = 0;
        this.anchoa = 1;

    }

    public void SetOffset(float off) {
        this.offset = off;
    }

    public void SetColor(int r1,int g1, int b1){        
        this.r=r1;
        this.g=g1;
        this.b=b1;
        this.color.setColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
    }

    public void CalcularPuntosPorcentaje(float px1, float py1,
            float porcentaje, float radio1) {
        this.anguloI = 0 + this.offset;
        this.px = px1;
        this.py = py1;
        this.radio = radio1;
        this.anguloI = 0;
        this.anchoa = porcentaje / 100 * 360;

        this.CalcularPuntos(px, py, anguloI, anchoa, radio);
    }

    public void CalcularPuntos(float px1, float py1, float anguloI1,
            float anchoangulo, float radio1) {
        this.anguloI = anguloI1 + this.offset;

        this.anchoa = anchoangulo;
        this.px = px1;
        this.py = py1;
        this.radio = radio1 ;

        float angulo = 360 - this.anguloI - this.anchoa;

        for (int i = 0; i < resolucion; i++) {
            this.puntox[i] = this.px - (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angulo))
                    * this.radio;
            this.puntoy[i] = this.py - (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angulo))
                    * this.radio;
            angulo = (360 - this.anguloI - this.anchoa)
                    + ((this.anchoa / (float) (this.resolucion)) * (i + 2));
        }

        this.circulo.reset();

        this.circulo.moveTo(this.px, this.py);
        for (int i = 0; i < resolucion; i++) {
            this.circulo.lineTo(this.puntox[i], this.puntoy[i]);
        }

    }

    public void ImprimeCirculo(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawPath(this.circulo, this.color);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this method:

```
canvas.drawArc(innerRect, -11.0f, 11.0f + 6.0f, true, paintx);
```

for docs see here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29

Be sure set the angle parameters correctly! And use float!

The first angle is the start of your arc and the second angle param is the sweep angle, ie how many degrees long should the angle be - measured clockwise.

Try it, it will work for sure. Just needs a little playing around  :-)

Comment: thanks user387184 for reply, i tried with below code                      paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  rect.set(100, 100, 100, 100);
  canvas.drawArc(rect, 100f, 100f + 6.0f, true, paint);
  canvas.restore();
  canvas.save(); . But the arc doesn't seem to show up

Comment: I just tried: Paint paintx = new Paint();
 paintx.setAntiAlias(true);
 paintx.setColor(Color.RED);
 canvas.drawArc(innerRect, 6.0f, 30.0f - 6.0f, true, paintx);
it works. If this does not work, then the problem is not with this piece of code. Check the rect and the canvas